# Is it possible to loop through user input in a visual flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

So if I have a textbox where the user can input account number (ex. 123,456,789), can I get the flow to separate the input by comma and find those accounts and update them? If so, can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may come across a similar problem, I found this extremely helpful article that basically did what I was needing: https://explorationsintosalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/divide-string-subflow/

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You would need to make an InvocableMethod to receive the text input, split the string, and return the list of values. You would have to decide if it is worth the effort of writing code to implement this. It'd be far simpler to just do this in Visualforce directly.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox input value can be assigned to a text variable. This text variable value can be parsed with several functions inside a loop until no other value is found. A record matching the value can be found using a flow element. This record value can be updated using an update element. It is possible.